# iOS Distribution Certificate - How to keep apps running

Tags: ios, certificate

Good morning, this is my first time dealing with an expiring iOS distribution certificate, so please pardon my noob question :(

I have personal unreleased apps running on my phone and Apple TV that are using this certificate. I was curious if theres a way to renew/create a new certificate that will not require me to reinstall these apps to my phone/Apple TV?

What is the normal process you do when your certificate is expiring?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apps don't use the certificate, the distributions certificates are only necessary to validade when sending an app. Your certificate can be revoked/expired and nothing will happen with your installed application or even ( if is the case ) your application on AppStore.

The only certificate that you need to care more is the PushNotification one, because if this one get expired/revoked your push server can't send notifications.